# A question on countable tightness of $X$

Tags: general-topology

For any topological space $X$, if $t(X)>\omega$, then there exists a non-closed set $A \subset X$ such that $\overline {B} \subset A$ for any countable $B \subset A$.

I cannot think out such set $A$. Could somebody help me?

> countable tightness = $X$ has countable tightness if for any $A \subset X$, whenever $x \in cl(A)$, then $x \in cl(B)$ for any countable $B \subset A$.

Comment: Start by spelling out precisely what $t(X) \gt \omega$ means.

Comment: I've wrote, however, I cannot deduce this result.

Comment: I don't see it written anywhere... If $t(X) \gt \omega$ then $\sup_{p \in X} t(p,X) + \omega \gt \omega$, so there is $p \in X$ such that $t(p,X) \gt \omega$. Now write what *that* means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$If $t(X)>\omega$, by definition there are a $B\subseteq X$ and an $x\in\cl B$ such that for all countable $C\subseteq B$, $x\notin\cl C$. Let $A=\bigcup\{\cl C:C\subseteq B\text{ and }|C|\le\omega\}$. Then $x\in(\cl A)\setminus A$, so $A$ is not closed. Let $C\subseteq A$ be countable. For each $y\in C$ there is a countable $C_Y\subseteq B$ such that $y\in\cl C_y$. Let $D=\bigcup_{y\in C}C_y$; then $D$ is a countable subset of $B$, so $\cl D\subseteq A$. But $C\subseteq\cl D$, so $\cl C\subseteq\cl D\subseteq A$, and $A$ has the desired properties.

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome.